# How to display a list of functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am creating a basic Todo app with ReactJS and I want to display the list of todos. I made a `todo` into a functional component and I create a `TodoList` component that should display the list. The problem is that when the `add` button is clicked, the todo is not added to the list and so the list is always empty.

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
  // Input tracker
  let input;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
    ref={node => {
      input = node;
    }}
      />
      <button
    onClick={() => {
      addTodo(input.value);
      input.value = "";
    }}
      >
    +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Todo = ({todo, remove}) => {
  // Each todo
  return <li onClick={remove(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</li>;
};

const TodoList = ({todos, remove}) => {
  // Map through the todos
  const todoNode = todos.map(todo => {
    return <Todo todo={todo} key={todo.id} remove={remove}/>;
  });
  return (
    <div className="list-group" style={{marginTop: "30px"}}>
      {todoNode}
    </div>
  );
};

const Title = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

// Container component
window.id = 0;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Pass props to parent class
    super(props);
    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.apiUrl = ""; // my url goes here
    // Make HTTP requests with axios
    axios.get(this.apiUrl).then(res => {
      // Set state with result
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    });
  }

  // addTodo hanlder
  addTodo(val) {
    // Assemble data
    const todo = {text: val, id: window.id++};
    // Update data
    this.state.data.push(todo);
    axios.post(this.apiUrl, todo).then(res => {
      this.state.data.push(res.data);
      this.setState({data: this.state.data});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <Title/>
    <TodoForm addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}/>
    <TodoList
      todos={this.state.data}
      remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
    />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's a screenshot of my app. The list should be displayed below the input text.

[image: my app right now]

I get 1 warning only, and no errors:

```
Line 86:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return
```

I think it is somewhere in my `addTodo` function, but I am not sure at all. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: u fount any error ?

Comment: @sayalok I have no error. There is 1 warning though. I'll update the question.

Comment: u keep ur data in state can u console it on ur app ? i think u should pass this data by props.

Comment: Can you please create demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addTodohandler` you are using this.state.data.push in React this will not update the state

```
addTodo(val) {
    // Assemble data
    const todo = {text: val, id: window.id++};
    axios.post(this.apiUrl, todo).then(res => {
      const newData = {...this.state.data, res.data}
      this.setState({data: newData });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

as said by warl0ck , the push does update your array but it React's render method doesn't update when you mutate an array you need to return a new Array that detects change and hence render is called